# here.com js-api, associate data with a point in polyline

Tags: javascript, gis

I would like to make an app in which the user may click anywhere along a polyline, and depending on the coordinate, get some info associated with that point (timestamp).
I'm designing an app to track where you have been at a given time... basically, I want to open an infobubble saying "you were here at -timestamp-".
What would be the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: How are you looking to store the information?  I would assume it would be done in one of two ways.  1.  You store information in a point layer with the attributes you'd want to display and query that when the point is clicked.  2.  You store data in a db with a x/y location then when a user clicks, you run a spatial query and find the one with the smallest distance from your table's x/y and the map click location.

Comment: I'll try that.. I was waiting to see if there was a way to set the data on individual points in a strip just as you can set the data associated with a whole strip.. So far what I tried was making a strip for every segment (instead of 1 strip for a set of points)... I set additional data on the strip using the setData() function.. I'm yet to find out how that is going to affect performance.